# Declaring an Array of Byte Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I declare an array of byte arrays with a limited size for the array? This is what I was thinking but it's not working and I couldn't find anything.

```
private Integer number =10000;
private byte[] data[];
data = new byte[][number];
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private byte[][] data;  // This is idiomatic Java

data = new byte[number][];
```

This creates an array of arrays.  However, none of those sub-arrays yet exist.  You can create them thus:

```
data[0] = new byte[some_other_number];
data[1] = new byte[yet_another_number];
...
```

(or in a loop, obviously).

Alternatively, if they're all the same length, you can do the whole thing in one hit:

```
data = new byte[number][some_other_number];
```

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Just to clarify, does that mean that I will have "number" byte arrays, each with an undetermined size?

Comment: @gtdevel: In that first code snippet, you will have an array of length `number`.  Each element of that array is a reference to a byte array, and is initialised to `null`.  i.e. `data[0] == null` is true.

Comment: @Zéychin: Not exactly.  See my above comment; it means you have "number" *references* to byte arrays; the byte arrays don't actually exist yet.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I understand what you are saying. Thanks.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You are correct. I've forgotten my place, as I too often discuss these sorts of things with people who know these details and so there it is often acceptable to omit them in description for brevity. +1 for the correction for the clarity of the original poster.

Answer (score 3):

may be you need a 2-d array

```
private byte[][] data = new byte[10][number];
```

that declares 10 byte arrays each of size number

Comment: And if I leave the "number" section blank, does that mean that the size could vary with each byte?

Comment: yes @gtdevel your understanding is correct.